# How to save FCM token automatically to server FCM registration token flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I am using firebase cloud messaging server to send notification to all users but i have to put the FCM token to firebase cloud messaging manually . My question is that how to add the token automatically here is my code to get the token in my app

```
   notificationsServices.RequestNotificationPermission();
notificationsServices.FirebaseInit(context);
//notificationsServices.IsTokenRefresh();
notificationsServices.getDeviceToken().then((value) {
  print('DEVICE TOKEN');
  print(value);
```

Comment: Just to confirm. What are you trying to do here? Are you trying to send your token to an app server? Or, retrieve the token from your app server and build a request to send notification?